# "Could not exchange access token for unknown reasons" ; In-meeting App Meeting Extension

Tags: javascript, teams-toolkit

Myself and a team member have followed the 'Try this sample' and 'Use the app in Teams' instructions for the In-Meeting sample application to develop an app for Microsoft Teams:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2/in-meeting-app

We've both followed the same steps on different computers and on different OS's (Mac and PC), and we are getting the same issue:

[image]

"An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded".

The instructions have us open Powershell and run commands in two locations. ('Try this sample' Step 5)

1. 'tabs' folder, asked to run npm install and npm start
2. 'bot' folder, asked to run npm install and npm run start:local

No errors occur when these commands are run initially, but when we open the app up in Teams and click on the button to bring out the side panel, errors show up in both terminals where we ran the commands.

In terminal 1, the tabs folder, we get a 'proxy error':

```html
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\tabs> npm install
up to date, audited 1685 packages in 2s

101 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

142 vulnerabilities (125 moderate, 16 high, 1 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
Compiled successfully!

You can now view microsoft-teams-ext in the browser.

  Local:            https://localhost:3000
  On Your Network:  https://192.168.0.3:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /getGraphAccessToken?ssoToken=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik1yNS1BVWliZkJpaTdOZDFqQmViYXhib1hXMCJ9.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.je5zMu4knsZ-NwqSKF1M_n71Ehxgs8WZGsPdIwUu0EBT3qdoHHL2ET4RqoTACqtMC8lDFqxFT2EWwYHcXes02QivXYEvWj8j-MQS-VhAs3FTh1e07qer8jq4cOeaVrLpfBjoCpSnbI_lXYUP-hz77YGWbUZrI6k5rXnij6-Jcn1TmvV9OgD_lrliWGIPHrS28TajvFa1Acu64YJGNAGys-r6uU7U5MrpcEszufRVExx8tDEysNWc55_Wr88Ur5mBIzDgDqiUbEf_RP2ZzlulRlPZC2ZVwI54VZqAWM2LfbCpD5bL9OhT7H9qAml5N8fOXY_WNHlYUWROgtD_iinQ from reflectrdomain.eu.rok.io to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

In terminal 2, the bot folder, we get a type error:

```html
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot> npm install

up to date, audited 188 packages in 1s

12 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
PS C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot> npm run start:local

> api-server@0.0.1 start:local
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development.local node ./index.js

API server is listening on port 5000
C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:192
            const connectorClient = this.createConnectorClientInternal(reference.serviceUrl, credentials);
                                                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'serviceUrl')
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:192:82)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:15:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:11:12)
    at BotFrameworkAdapter.continueConversation (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\botFrameworkAdapter.js:165:16)
    at C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\index.js:144:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Luke\TeamsApps\in-meeting-app\bot\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

My team member who is on Mac, instead of getting the error I get above, just gets the message "Could not exchange access token for unknown reasons.", but his client displays the same behaviour.

These errors repeat each time we open and close the side panel.

What can we do to fix the issue, and get it to show as it's supposed to?

[image]

Steps to reproduce:
Follow steps at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v2/in-meeting-app

"An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using this sample and post the issue.

For the first error occurred in tab folder, from the log

> reflectrdomain.eu.rok.io to http://localhost:5000/

I found that you may not using the ngrok, so caused the proxy error, my suggestion is try ngrok first and check if it is worked.

The solution for the second issue in bot folder, is removed the app in the meeting and re-add the app into the meeting.

Comment: Hi Jerry - thanks for your answer. We are using Ngrok, but only on port 3000 (as per the instructions) - we are running 'ngrok http --region=eu --hostname=reflectrdomain.eu.ngrok.io https://localhost:3000', which opens up a new tunnel for the domain reflectrdomain.eu.ngrok.io to localhost 3000. We are not running Ngrok on port 5000 - do we need to be? Also, for the bot folder issue, removing and adding the app does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Link I tried the sample in my environment, it works well, so what the difference between us is the ngrok, you changed the hostname. But it seems the error occurred from the proxy. I have not found reason yet.
You do not need to run Ngrok on port 5000.
Removing the app means in Manage apps delete it.

Comment: Hi Jerry - thanks. We still haven't got it working, so we've decided to go for a 'Wizard of Oz' implementation due to time constraints.